# How can I connect to mysql in dialogflow fulfillment?

Tags: mysql, dialogflow-es

I want to connect to my mysql by using mysql.createConnection.
but it doesn't work.
 - Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306

I use server for mysql.
And I already try server's IP in 'host'
 - Error: connect ETIMEDOUT

1. createConnection

   const connection = mysql.createConnection({
     host: 'localhost',
     user: 'user name',
     password: 'password',
     database: 'db name',
     acquireTimeout: 60000,
     connectTimeout: 60000,
     port: 3306
   });
   connection.connect(function(err){
     if (err) console.log('connection error:'+err);
   });
2. createPool

   const pool = mysql.createPool({
     connectionLimit: 10,
     acquireTimeout: 30000,
     host: 'localhost',  //127.0.0.1
     user: 'user name',
     password: 'password',
     database: 'db name'
   });

Here is all code for connection.

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',  
  user: 'user name',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'db name',
  acquireTimeout: 60000,
  connectTimeout: 60000,
  port: 3306
});
connection.connect(function(err){
  if (err) console.log('connection error:'+err);
});

const pool = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: 10,
  acquireTimeout: 30000,
  host: 'localhost',  //127.0.0.1
  user: 'user name',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'db name'
});
```

Comment: It looks like the server is not running. Please check that the server is running, is configured to accept connections via tcp/ip (check the `my.cnf` file) and that there is no firewall issues. Also, check the log files of the MySQL server.

Comment: Where are you running this code? You've tagged it "dialogflow" - does this mean you're using the Dialogflow built-in fulfillment editor?